# Systemjs loading for angular2 project shows 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error when my static contents are in different domain

Tags: angular, systemjs

When I am using systemjs loader with angular2 and my static contents are in different domain I am getting `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`.

But if I install Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * chrome plugin everything works fine.

full error message:

```
http://www.different-domain.com/app/main.js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have added allow access origin in my server and its working with normal `<script>` tag and jQuery script loader, so I am sure there is no problem with server or client. It looks like the problem is with systemjs loader which does not allow to get data from different domain.

Comment: You need to fix that in your server. This is not Angular2 related. Just search for the error message